# Is TDengine suitable to store large text fields?

Tags: tdengine

I need to migrate my database from PostgreSQL to the TDengine since most of them are time-series data. But there is a text field in the table for storing large chunks of text.

May I know if TDengine is suitable to store large chunks of text with any data type?
How long the maximum length of nchar is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create TDengine table with 16374-bytes `binary` and 16374/4=4093 `nchar`

```sql
create table tb1(ts timestamp, vv binary(16374), nchar(4093))
```